# 64 unsigned integers in Lua 5.3/5.4 do not behave like in "Programming in Lua"

Tags: lua, unsigned-integer

I'm reading "Programming in Lua, Forth Edition", and I'm stuck on exercise 13.1, because Lua does not seem to behave like in the book. The section 13.2, about Unsigned Integers, states:

```
> x = 13835058055282163712   -- 3ul << 62ul
> x                          --> -4611686018427387904
```

But if I do that in Lua 5.4, Windows x64, or Lua 5.3, WSL x64, they both behave like this:

```
> x = 13835058055282163712
> x
1.3835058055282e+19
> math.type(x)
float
```

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Why does "the book" about learning Lua 5.3, shows examples not matching actual Lua implementations? Is that due to some later update to the language?
2. Is there a work-around? How to I write large "unsigned integers" in decimal, without them being turned into floats?

Comment: Note that Lua cannot natively store integers larger than 2^63 without making them float and thus losing precision. You'd have use a library specifically made for operations on arbitrarily large integers, or just store them as strings, if all you need is to write them. But that is really a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time the book was written (it corresponds to Lua version 5.3.0) Lua had wrong behavior of reading long integer literals: it wraparounded them.
Later, in Lua 5.3.3 this behavior [has been corrected](https://github.com/lua/lua/commit/10b0b09555920ad2ac186274348e73ed61cede90) to a more user-friendly.
As for now, when a decimal integer literal in beyond int64 range, Lua reads it as float number to preserve its numeric value.  Hexadecimal integer literals are wraparounded.

Comment: So, basically, if I want to enter an "unsigned integer", that can be represented with 64 bits, but bigger than the maximum value of a 64-bit "singed integer", I *have to* use hexadecimal (but then, it *doesn't* get converted to a float?)

Comment: Hexadecimal positive values from `2^63` to `2^64-1` will be converted to negative int64 values.  Hexadecimal integer literals will not be converted to float, but their high bits (above 64) will be ignored, and low 64 bits will be saved to signed int64.